# aligning header in table without affecting decimal alignment in the corresponding column

Tags: tables, xetex, tabularx

I have problems aligning the headers to their corresponding column without affecting the alignment of the decimals. How can I do this more automatically?

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc*{2}{S[table-format=-1.5]}
                       S[table-format=1.3]
                       S
                       S[table-format=-1.3]
                       S[table-format= 3.5]
                       S[table-format= 1.3]
                       }
\toprule
\textbf{Sensor} & \textbf{ID} & $\mathbf{k_1}$ & $\mathbf{k_2}$ & $\mathbf{p_1}$ & $\mathbf{p_2}$ & $\mathbf{k_3}$ \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Infrared}} & A & -0.1648 & 0.7673 & 0.0069 & 0.0064 & -1.3135 \\
& B & -0.1480 & 0.6950 & 0.0079 & 0.0017  & -1.2501 \\
& C & -0.0992 & 0.2648 & 0.0022 & -0.0036 & -0.2833 \\
& D & -0.1933 & 1.1570 & 0.0002 & 0.0039  & -2.4079 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{RGB}} & A & 0.0288 & -0.1249 & 0.0070 & 0.0056 & -0.0506 \\
& B & 0.0093 & -0.1718 & 0.0124  & 0.0048  & 0.1517 \\
& C & 0.0803 & -0.4595 & 0.0072  & -0.0008 & 0.5304 \\
& D & 0.0187 &  0.0259 & -0.0009 & 0.0030  & -0.2990 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The usual trick is to use \multicolumn for a single column.  I tried to test it, but cannot figure out what package S comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With give only sniped of your table without document preamble you make work harder to anyone who wish to help you ...

In your table column heads are exactly on the column middle. You just need to correct set the number columns (you define 9 columns, however table has only 7) and number formats (all `S` column types are the same: sign and 1.4):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc*{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                }
\toprule
\textbf{Sensor} & \textbf{ID} & $\mathbf{k_1}$ & $\mathbf{k_2}$ & $\mathbf{p_1}$ & $\mathbf{p_2}$ & $\mathbf{k_3}$ \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Infrared}} & A & -0.1648 & 0.7673 & 0.0069 & 0.0064 & -1.3135 \\
& B & -0.1480 & 0.6950 & 0.0079 & 0.0017  & -1.2501 \\
& C & -0.0992 & 0.2648 & 0.0022 & -0.0036 & -0.2833 \\
& D & -0.1933 & 1.1570 & 0.0002 & 0.0039  & -2.4079 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{RGB}} & A & 0.0288 & -0.1249 & 0.0070 & 0.0056 & -0.0506 \\
& B & 0.0093 & -0.1718 & 0.0124  & 0.0048  & 0.1517 \\
& C & 0.0803 & -0.4595 & 0.0072  & -0.0008 & 0.5304 \\
& D & 0.0187 &  0.0259 & -0.0009 & 0.0030  & -0.2990 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]